# Function scrollIntoView doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, js-scrollintoview

I have a little problem with my function `scrollIntoView`. Indeed, it doesn't work :(

This is my code:

- HTML

  ```
  <section class="page_mission">
    <div class="page_mission_text">
      <div class="scroll-animations">
        <div class="animated fadeInLeft">
          <h2>Design <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></h2>
          <p>Blablabla<br></p>
        </div><hr style="width: 75%;">
        <div class="animated">
          <h2>Modernité <i class="fas fa-dna"></i></h2>
          <p>Blablabla</p>
        </div><hr style="width: 75%;">
        <div class="animated">
          <h2>Coûts <a href="cost_popup.html" class="ajax-popup-link"><i class="far fa-credit-card"></i></a></h2>
          <p>Blablabla</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  ```
- JS

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
         var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
         var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

         var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
         var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

         return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
      }

      $(window).scroll(function() {
          $('.scroll-animations .animated').each(function() {
              if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
                  $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');

              }
      });
  });
  ```

Does someone have an idea what's wrong?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is not working? What does happen when you run what you have? Does the console window show any errors?

Comment: Yes there is an error : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):153

Comment: and when I run, there is nothing happening :/

Comment: Can you post the code which coincides with the line number 153?

Comment: Sorry. The code is "$(document).ready(function() {" the first line of my JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me the `fadeInLeft` class is being added on scroll as expected. You do, however, need an additional closing curly brace and closing parentheses to close your document ready event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {

  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;

  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    $('.scroll-animations .animated').each(function() {

      if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {

        $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');

      }

    });
  });

}); // This was missing
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnx9bo1o/)

You also need to make sure to load jQuery before your JavaScript executes. The easiest way is to place something like this in the page's `<head>` element:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but, after the modification, there is enough a problem. And I have this error in my console ; Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):153

Comment: You have to make sure jQuery is loaded before the scripts run.

Comment: That's why the JSFiddle works. It automatically pulls in jQuery before running the rest of the page.

Comment: How can I have sure that my jQuery code is loaded ? Thanks you for your answer :)

Comment: Wiht this is enough no ? <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

Comment: @DavidMeurisse you bet. It depends on the page. The easiest way is to include something like this in the page's `head` element: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`